# How to view POST data from previous form submission?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, cms

I'm using Google Chrome and have been working in a rather clunky and rediculous CMS.

I've been making some CSS edits using Chrome Developer Tools and then copying and pasting it into a large textarea in the CMS. I have then hit the 'update' button on the CMS in which I relised afterwards that I've just copied and pasted the wrong CSS in the wrong textarea thus overwriting 100s of lines incorrecty.

Unluckily for me the CMS also does a redirect to a 'cms homepage' after posting data and all the calls to load the edit page are ajax. All this is making the back button completely useless.

I'll I can confirm is that the data would have been posted to the server. Is there a way to sniff around on my computer to find this post data? I can't just click back or anything else on google crhome thanks to the CMS!

I'm seriously about to flip out if I can't find a way to retrieve this previously posted data. HELP!

Comment: Backups? I don't really see how the post data will help you anyway.

Comment: the last hope I'll find will be the cache directory of your browser.  btw, i think you should thanks AJAX rather than CMS, AJAX sucks in such case (you can't use the history of browser to get your old form data back)